# Is it possible to run Smalltalk scripts from the command line?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I found a (possibly outdated and incorrect) [blog post from 2004](http://www.ianbicking.org/where-smalltalk-went-wrong.html) which claimed that it was impossible to run Smalltalk scripts from the command line. Has anything changed since then, and is it possible to run Smalltalk scripts from the command line? I've done a lot of Google searching, and I've found no information about this topic at all.

Is there any way to save a Smalltalk script (such as this one) as a file, and then run the script from the command line?

```
Transcript show: 'This should be printed to the standard output.' printString; cr.
```

Comment: Which smalltalk are you using?  Pharo has Coral at http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/coral/

Comment: @msandiford I'm using GST Smalltalk, but I might be able to use Pharo as well, depending on whether there are any syntactic differences between GNU Smalltalk and Pharo. (In fact, I'm not even sure whether there are significant syntactic differences between each Smalltalk implementation).

Comment: @msandiford Also, I still don't understand the instructions for generating the Coral shell scripts. According to the [Getting Started guide](http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/coral/getting-started.html), I should "put these files at the right place before generating the scripts", but the guide doesn't explain where to put the files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Pharo](http://pharo.org) has decent command line support and a simple [zeroconf](http://get.pharo.org) script to install it:

```
curl get.pharo.org | bash
./pharo Pharo.image --help
./pharo Pharo.image eval "1+2"
```

We use these tools on a regular basis on our [ci servers](http://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution).

New command line handles can be installed easily by subclassing.
You will find a partial documentation [here](http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/ZeroConf.pdf).

[Coral](https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/Coral/) aims at more complex interfaces and supports complex parameter parsing. The default command line tools shipped with Pharo follow a rather simplistic approach and you have to check and process parameters manually.

Comment: The documentation you cited shows using `stdin` with `eval`, e.g., `echo "1+2" | $PHARO_VM my.image eval`. With Pharo 6.1 it's not working under ubuntu 17 (the command hangs). It's working with the expression as an argument passed in. I'm trying to find a way to evaluate arbitrary scripts from a file, e.g., `cat myScript | ...` without defining the command handler (subclassing, etc.) inside an image.

Comment: OK, I'm using the `st` command once I renamed my script `myScript.st`. That is `./pharo Pharo.image st myScript.st` is working with arbitrary Pharo commands. Nice!

Answer (score 13):

With gst, it's straightforward. Put this into hi.st:

```
Transcript show: 'Hi!'
```

Then run `gst hi.st` and you're done.

To pass arguments from the command line, you do as follows:

```
Transcript show: 'Hi ' , Smalltalk arguments first , '!'
```

Then run `gst hi.st -a World`

Comment: Further information can be found in the gst documentation: http://smalltalk.gnu.org/documentation

Answer (score 2):

Running a script from the command line is trivial with pretty much any Squeak version, certainly 5.3 or newer.

Basically
`{path/to/myVM} {path/to/myscript}`

That myscript argument can be a URL pointing to a smalltalk code file or simply a filename. Since Smalltalk can read both code to install and code to run directly from a file, you can add some new code  - consider it 'script functions' if you like - and then run whatever you want. So, at least on a unix machine, you can make a shell script that runs your VM and appends the filename of your intended script, and thus do sometihng like
`myshellscript mystuff.st`

As an example, consider a script to work out and print the first Fibonacci number that requires one million digits.

```
#!/usr/bin/squeak /home/pi/Squeak/Squeak5.3-18560.image

!Integer methodsFor: 'mathematical functions' stamp: 'tpr 5/6/2019 12:22'!
fibonacci
"derived from https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms"
"(1 to: 20) collect:[:i| i fastDoublingFib]"
"testing a quite large one - "
"8577 fibonacci= 13724780954457889052017147206983806244049002655849289934662148526555403650297300643609932653364630032094175733360509578504423049114004867523161091564824674600978308740378989479162611031273424686573759784740689516901416473328655422390895971263265867635819510949686102571388751758998017349379498918930220900180038324615253426530740473855269056304380498630108126734047701362218655030270360608989081398866489746698916626888016696892691933237089180504631788915650757757515944644732966345269202761471025651071790297611079540881155092137592980230998234868586211881093892491570520577408961869977892273540956424095750855208529072246641778982103984467921868950012668004047986803017482248992968482737462668300684879633714025755790485860328854796518843956263863014632532331145699658530054942590047273403691531821918862996422405159427262092477196755988981309029424760342802374213122162727840557722145891090413688461745240415668189577836068480363407847582529735341950500636735281963089675493707159434777756081146452522323681782226760627277553296721358921412115264845467834979154061137421532609247762981818564578019888974692581079593575783553856910367568474613323528337733872069223030834774749130478360574004172522316484339530942110067893000847800932306298725285623628731149337468217751734165148732164148285915275115006479682658150442259002271790547596033006363411193653337536041106069912826015502035140618407668385378737477702597473151509972754111640855347958033314453349633268543893894677097708945041254623018915871109789412793709229204261914803477697183287924195770678873001065036313926288444791424871512110658175954743584548831946767673488152740675550518235698898217693311515366329280005757014637854214769152690638778904780724293185353992279724740604674926819294787586671833537117545443846365508358918882"
    | a b c |
    a :=  0.
    b := 1.
    self highBit to: 1 by: -1 do:[:i||d e|
        d := ((b bitShift: 1) - a) * a.
        e := a squared + b squared.
        a := d.
        b := e.
        (self bitAt: i) = 1  ifTrue:[
            c := a + b.
            a := b.
            b := c]
        ].
    ^a! !


| t f|
t:= [f := 4784969 fibonacci] timeToRun.
FileStream stdout
    nextPutAll: 'fib(4784969) = '; 
    "nextPutAll: f asString; "
    cr; 
    nextPutAll: 'time = '; 
    nextPutAll: t asString; 
    nextPutAll: ' mS'; 
    cr.
Smalltalk snapshot: false andQuit: true
```

If you save this and set it to be executable the first line would run the script (this is from a Raspberry Pi and /usr/bin/squeak is a standard part of the distro) with the name of the script as the argument. It loads a bit of code to implement an interestingly clever algorithm, runs the test, outputs to stdout, and finally quits. It takes about 3 seconds on a Pi 4.
Simply running the .st file will now work -
`./myscript`

It is, apparently, also possible to do clever tricks and register a magic pattern with the binfmt_misc facility so one could make st files have their own equivalent of the #! token.

Answer (score 1):

Not much has changed, that blog post is even more wrong now than it was then. Now we have a real headless vm and image in Pharo, and we can make much smaller images by bootstrapping them with only the classes needed.

Comment: This should be the favorite answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
gst - <<<"'hello' printNl"
```

This is a universal pattern for supplying a script on the command line. It is called a here string. The dash is setting the file name to standard input, and the triple less than makes the following string a in place file on standard in. You still get command line parameter expansion.

You can get a lot fancier with [here documents](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) that let you type in multiline commands in a script or right on the command line with double less than.

Here documents are portable to any Bourne shell; here strings are a Bash extension.