# creating a CLI in Pharo

Tags: pharo

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass arguments to a an object in the pharo image via the command line.

I know how to start the image from the command line by

`pharovm image.image`

But how can I register an object to respond to the next arguments that would be passed?

`pharovm image.image do something`

Comment: see this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256534/is-it-possible-to-run-smalltalk-scripts-from-the-command-line

Comment: Perfect that's just what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Smalltalk scripts from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256534/is-it-possible-to-run-smalltalk-scripts-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Do you are found answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256534/is-it-possible-to-run-smalltalk-scripts-from-the-command-line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLAP library, that would support CLI parameters: https://github.com/pharo-contributions/clap-st

Then you can run something like `./pharovm --headless pharo.image clap yourCommand yourParameter`